# I don't how know to set panels + grid in a frames with wxpython

Tags: python, grid, wxpython, panel

I have this python code [my problem with wxpython](http://pastebin.com/LPpQ4gJX)
I use last wxpython with Python 2.7.

What should I do if I want to use the commented code and use more panels, being the grid
visible?

I tried it in many ways, and I'm totally unable to do anything.
The problem is that the application crashes, or it doesn't shows properly.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
class MyGrid(gridlib.Grid):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateGrid(2, 3)


        # test all the events

//Code for events

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="An Eventful Grid",size=(700,700))
        p = wx.Panel(self)

        # IF I UNCOMMNT THIS ,IT DOESNT LOADS THE WINDOW OR GRID APPEARS CORRUPTED
        #self.panel = p1 = wx.Panel(self,pos=(0,200),size=(100,100))
        #button2 = wx.Button(p1, -1, label="click me")
        #wx.StaticText(p, -1,"Right-click on the panel to show a popup menu",(100,100))
        #self.panel = p2 = wx.Panel(self,pos=(200,200),size=(400,200))
        myGrid = MyGrid(p)


        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)#,pos=(200,200)
        #sizer.Add(p2, 2, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and include a minimal example showing the problem in your question?  Read about the markup to learn how to embed your code (the orange question mark).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code to get it to work, and here's the output and the code:

[image]

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib
class MyGrid(gridlib.Grid):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateGrid(2, 3)

class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="An Eventful Grid",size=(700,700))
        p = wx.Panel(self)

        button2 = wx.Button(p, -1, label="click me")
        st = wx.StaticText(p, -1,"Right-click on the panel to show a popup menu")
        p2 = wx.Panel(p, size=(400,200))
        p2.SetBackgroundColour((100, 0, 0))
        myGrid = MyGrid(p)


        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(button2)
        sizer.Add(st)
        sizer.Add(myGrid, 1, wx.EXPAND)#,pos=(200,200)
        sizer.Add(p2, 2, wx.EXPAND)
        p.SetSizer(sizer)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I hope this works for you, since I didn't take the time to try to guess exactly what you were going for.

A few things that were problematic in your original:

1) it's not advisable to combine absolute positions and sizes with sizers.  Just stick to one or the other (preferably sizers).

2) You had a bunch of conflicting placements and parents.  For example, panel `p` was put in the frame (ie, p = `wx.Panel(self...` ) and then another (ie, `p1 = wx.Panel(self,...` ) but then you didn't say how to add these to the sizer.  First, not everything needs to have it's own panel, so I just added the button directly.  More importantly, you need to add everything into the sizer, and be consistent with setting the right parent.

If, say, you wanted the button and statictext in its own panel (say, p5, with p as it's parent), you could do that by: making the panel, adding in the button and the static text, and then adding panel p5 to the sizer.

Comment: Awesome ,i'm new in all this whole thing thanks for you pro code!

Comment: Happy to help.  If you think this completely answers your question, you might want to click the check mark to accept it.  This will save other people time, so they won't read over you question and my answer seeing whether or not it's been answered.